# How can I optimise this C++?

Tags: c++, optimization, g++, pypy

I am trying to practice C++ by doing some old Google Code Jam problems. A relatively simple one I found is to reverse the words in a string. It can be found here https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/351101/dashboard#s=p1

So far I have:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n = 0;
    cin >> n;


    string rev = "";
    string buf = "";

    string data = "";
    getline(cin, data);

    for(int _ = 0; _ < n; _++){
        getline(cin, data);

        rev = "";
        buf = "";
        for(char& c : data) {
            buf += c;
            if(c == ' '){
                rev = buf + rev;
                buf = "";
            }
        }

        cout << "Case #" << _ + 1 << ": " << buf << " " << rev << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Which seems to run pretty fast. When running `time ./reverse < in > /dev/null` with a test file of around `1.2E6` cases it takes around `3.5` seconds when compiled with `g++ -O3`.

So as a benchmark I created a solution in python

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from sys import stdin, stdout
stdout.writelines(map(lambda n: "Case #%d: %s\n" % (n + 1, ' '.join(stdin.readline().split()[::-1])), xrange(int(stdin.readline()))))
```

However when I run it under `pypy` with `time pypy reverse.py < in > /dev/null` it takes only about `1.95` seconds.

In theory as `pypy` is written in C++ shouldn't C++ be as fast or faster and if so how could this code be optimised to be faster ?

Comment: You really shouldn't use "_" as a variable name, if nothing else just as a style thing, but starting variables with _ or __ often has special meaning for some compilers.

Comment: @PherricOxide Identifiers starting with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter and identifiers containing double underscores are reserved for the implementation. This applies to _all_ compilers.

Comment: Thanks for telling me. I think I used it originally because I didn't think I needed it and I guess it is just a habit from coding in python where if there is a variable you don't need in a for loop I found most just call it "_". Anyway changing it doesn't seem to make much difference to the time.

Comment: if you want *really* good perfomance, drop the C++ io stuff and strings...

Comment: But doesn't the problem require "io stuff" and involve the manipulation of "strings". How could I solve it without?

Comment: plain old C, char*, malloc...

Comment: "`pypy` is written in C++" - Say what? It isn't. There are a few pieces of C, but otherwise it's written in RPython.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple non-copying/non-allocating tokenizer is the abominable [std::strtok](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtok)

The following beats your python program in my tests

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    std::cout.sync_with_stdio(false); // we don't need C in the picture

    std::string line;
    getline(std::cin, line);
    int num_cases = stoi(line);

    std::vector<char*> words;
    for(int n = 0; getline(std::cin, line) && n < num_cases; ++n)
    {   
        words.clear();
        char* p = std::strtok(&line[0], " ");
        while (p) {
            words.push_back(p);
            p = std::strtok(nullptr, " ");
        }
        std::cout << "Case #" << n + 1 << ": ";
        reverse_copy(words.begin(), words.end(),
                     std::ostream_iterator<char*>(std::cout, " "));
        std::cout << '\n'; // never std::endl!
    }
}
```

PS: your C++ and python outputs don't match exactly; this program matches your C++ output

Comment: WOW! `1.2` seconds. That's fast! I was unaware of std::strtok, but it certainly performs well for this. Thanks. Also, I thought my C++ and Python code did the same thing how exactly do they differ?

Comment: @luke python isn't printing an extra space at the end of each line

Answer (score 1):

I think your C++ code is doing quite a few memory copies when you concatenate strings (most implementations of std::string keep the entire string contiguous in memory.)  I think the following code does this without copies, but I did not test it much.  As to why the python performs quite well, I'm not entirely sure.

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    size_t numCases;
    std::cin >> numCases;
    std::cin.ignore();

    for( size_t currentCase = 1; currentCase <= numCases; ++currentCase )
    {
        std::cout << "Case #" << currentCase << ": ";

        std::string line;
        getline(std::cin, line);
        size_t wordEnd = line.length() - 1;
        size_t lastSpace = std::string::npos;
        for ( int pos = wordEnd - 1; pos >= 0; --pos )
        {
            if ( line[pos] == ' ' )
            {
                for ( int prt = pos + 1; prt <= wordEnd; ++prt )
                    std::cout << line[prt];
                std::cout << ' ';
                lastSpace = pos;
                wordEnd = pos - 1;
                --pos;
            }
        }
        for ( int prt = 0; prt < lastSpace; ++prt )
            std::cout << line[prt];

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When compiling under `g++ -O3` this actually seems to be slower when running `time ./reverse < in > /dev/null` as it takes about 4.5 seconds.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of using two buffers and lots of concatenation, you could leverage off of the algorithms and iterator libraries to do it all much simpler. I'm not sure how much faster it would be (though I would guess quite a but), but it is also much more compact.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<iterator>
#include<sstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n = 0;
    cin >> n;
    string data = "";
    getline(cin, data);
    for(int _ = 0; _ < n; _++){
        getline(cin, data);
        stringstream ss(data);
        reverse(istream_iterator<string>(ss), istream_iterator<string>());
        cout << "Case #" << _ + 1 << ": " << ss.str() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When attempting to compile your code I get: ` error: ‘ss’ was not declared in this scope.

Comment: #include <sstream> sorry about that